# Await until assertJ asserts true on database update

Tags: java, testing, assertj

I am running a test that sends some data to a database and checks it's all been inserted properly. Depending on the machine, this can take varying amounts of time. I am using awaitly/assertj. Is there a way of rerunning the tests up to a maximum time to ensure im giving enough time for the database to update? Something akin to:

```
awaitly.untilAssertionsAreTrue(() -> {
  assertThat(expected).isEqualTo(database);
});
```

I have tried untilAsserted but it just runs instantly.

Comment: Can you show the code under test as well?

Comment: The code receives messages from a message queue and sends it to mongo. This logic works fine, it's just the timescale.

Comment: I am not doubting about it, but you can receive much more help if you show the code, there may be different approaches than the one you're suggesting

Comment: The code is on a seperate PC that can't access stack overflow.

The test itself currently is:

```
await.untilAsserted(() -> {
long id = mongo.findOne(Query.query(Criteria.where("id").is(1234)), My.Class).getId();
  assertThat(id).isNotNull();
assertThat(messagesProcessed).isEqualTo(1234);
});
```

Comment: In that case it's hard to help you. You definitely need to synchronize the assertion with the operation performed, but without seeing how the operation is performed, I doubt anyone can tell you how to synchronize it